# Indexing multi-lingual content with Lucene.net

Tags: search, localization, lucene.net, multilingual

I use [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for indexing content & documents etc.. on websites. The index is very simple and has this format:

```
LuceneId - unique id for Lucene (TypeId + ItemId)
TypeId   - the type of text (eg. page content, product, public doc etc..)
ItemId   - the web page id, document id etc..
Text     - the text indexed
Title    - web page title, document name etc.. to display with the search results
```

I've got these options to adapt it to serve multi-lingual content:

1. Create a separate index for each language. E.g. Lucene-enGB, Lucene-frFR etc..
2. Keep the one index and add an additional 'language' field to it to filter the results.

Which is the best option - or is there another? I've not used multiple indexes before so I'm leaning toward the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do [2], but one problem I have is that I cannot use different analyzers depending on the language. I've combined the stopwords of the languages I want, but I lose the capability of more advanced stuff that the analyzer will offer such as stemming etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate option 1 and 2.
 
You can use one index and the fields that contains arabic words create two fileds for each:
If you have field "**Text**" might contain arabic or english contents ==>

- Create 2 fields for "**Text**" : 1 field, "**Text**", indexed/searched with your standard analyzer and another one, "**Text_AR**" , with the arabicAnalyzer. In order to achieve that you can use 
  [PreFieldAnalyzerWrapper](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dc/df9/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_per_field_analyzer_wrapper.html#details)