# languages supported by lucene.net

Tags: lucene.net

-What all languages supported by Lucene.net?

-For eg. chinese,russian,japanese,arabic,french,german etc.

-If not, is there is any way to index other languages?

Comment: What type of language-specific functionality are you asking about? Stemming? Synonyms?

Answer (score 7):

**Lucene is not limited to English, nor any other language.** To index text properly, you need to use an Analyzer appropriate for the language of the text you are indexing. Lucene's default Analyzers work well for English. There are a number of other Analyzers in Lucene Sandbox, including those for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean.

Here is a list of analyzer which you can integrated with your Lucene.NET:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/trunk/src/contrib/Analyzers/

As you can see above lots of language are already included in the analyzers and if not included, go ahead and create it because if it is not listed only means, no one tried it yet, however it does not mean it is not supported.

Also read this SO discussion on [Indexing multi-lingual content with Lucene.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553404/indexing-multi-lingual-content-with-lucene-net)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest version.
https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_1/analyzers-common/index.html

Google the latest version of Lucene and change the version number in the link for the latest versions in time of your search.