# Improving search performance on websites database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Is there any way to improve this query, I am quite satisfied by the results returned but performance is really bad, does union in this case causes round-trip? Would something like this be possible by using Stored Procedure to gain on preformance? Is it possible to do something like self join on results and would it increase performance?

```
        List<string> words = Util.Search.SplitByWhiteSpace(q);

        using (WebsitesDataContext context = new WebsitesDataContext())
        {
            IQueryable<WebsitesRanked> query = Enumerable.Empty<WebsitesRanked>().AsQueryable();
            query = query.Union(context.Websites.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(q)).Select(x => new WebsitesRanked { Webiste = x, Rank = 100 }));
            query = query.Union(context.Websites.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(q)).Select(x => new WebsitesRanked { Webiste = x, Rank = 100 }));
            query = query.Union(context.Websites.Where(x => x.Keywords.Contains(q)).Select(x => new WebsitesRanked { Webiste = x, Rank = 100 }));
            query = query.Union(context.Websites.Where(x => x.Url.Contains(q)).Select(x => new WebsitesRanked { Webiste = x, Rank = 100 }));

            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                string keyword = word;
                query = query.Union(context.Websites.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(word)).Select(x => new WebsitesRanked { Webiste = x, Rank = 20 }));
                query = query.Union(context.Websites.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(word)).Select(x => new WebsitesRanked { Webiste = x, Rank = 20 }));
                query = query.Union(context.Websites.Where(x => x.Keywords.Contains(word)).Select(x => new WebsitesRanked { Webiste = x, Rank = 20 }));
                query = query.Union(context.Websites.Where(x => x.Url.Contains(word)).Select(x => new WebsitesRanked { Webiste = x, Rank = 20 }));
            }

           var results = query.GroupBy(x => x.Webiste).Select(x => new WebsitesRanked { Webiste = x.First().Webiste, Rank =  x.Sum(s => s.Rank) }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Rank).Select(x => x.Webiste);
        }
```

Comment: Use [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) or Sql Server's [full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Comment: @L.B I looked at documentation of Linq to Lucene, and as far sa I saw it requeires to create new field with all fields in one long string. So I can't know in which column match was found, am I right? And this way I can filter over-optimized websites, with spam keywords.

Comment: Don't use Linq2Lucene it is a wrapper, Just use pure Lucene.Net. You can define many "field"s with different contents in a single "document".

Comment: @L.B [languages supported by lucene.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971261/languages-supported-by-lucene-net) Acorrding to this question I don't think it it such a good idea since I have 30+ languages and each would require analyzer?

Comment: You can use AsciiFoldingFilter which remove diacritics and index all languages easily with a single analyzer. That said, I see you are trying to find reasons not to use it. OK. don't. It has of course a learning curve. But I bet you would get amazed with its speed.

Comment: @L.B Now that you mentioned, it has a steep learning curve, I actully wanted to find out if it suits all my needs before rushing into learning it. But it looks like I will have to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

you can create dictionary table:
one table partition by letter (table partition for word starting with 'a', another 'b'...)
this table will have those columns:

```
column 1:Word (each word in your table will be setted here using a nightly schedule task or Background schedule task)
column 2:Website 
column 3:Rank (each time a word is found, increment this rank)
```

with only one table to query and using partition to be performant, you will have good performance because the work will be done for you on a schedule task

Comment: I have 30+ languages for now, which will increase more, but good Idea for only one language.